# MirrorLink and ADB in parallel

Tags: usb, adb

Is it possible to use MirrorLink and Android Debug Bridge in parallel?
I'm working on a third party MirrorLink application and want to debug it with ADB/logcat.

Actually I've tried to use ADB over wifi and it works very good. But when I started the MirrorLink session, the connection got lost and couldn't be established again until the MirrorLink session was over.

Answer (score 1):

We actually use the ADB when testing some ML devices, but I don't think we actually use it while in in an active MirrorLink session. There is nothing explicitly preventing it within MirrorLink that prevents it - but there may be some interaction vai UPnP or the MirrorLink attestation mechanism.

I've talked to some of the ML server (phone) device makers about this. You should be able to run ADB during a ML session via the WiFi connection. You have to do some work to enable ADB over wifi, but there is a handy guide on doing so here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html

Answer (score 0):

ADB and MirrorLink use different USB drivers and application software stacks. The capability is depends on the design of host and device side in terms of USB role. Some of the devices can run more than one driver and application at a time. However, some of them are limited to run one and exclusive from other drivers.

You may try use the method from the answer provided by Ed P. ADB forward through Wi-Fi is an alternative.